# Creating a login page for custom Django users?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-users

I am trying to write a webapp that allows users to match, and meet other users, based on interests. I am in early stages and have written a registration page, and used a custom user model to register users. I'd like those users to be able to login to their profile and make any necessary changes/view their profile.

My current login page is always simply refreshing, as it can't seem to log into any profiles, even though the credentials are fine.

**Custom user Model:**

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    """
    Custom user class.
    """
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField('email address', unique=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
    interests = models.ManyToManyField(Interest)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email
```

**Current Login form:**

```
class AuthenticationForm(forms.Form):
    """
    Login form
    """
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        fields = ['email', 'password']
```

**Finally, the current login view:**

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = authenticate(email=request.POST['email'], password=request.POST['password'])
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    django_login(request, user)
                    return redirect('/success/')
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render_to_response('login.html', {
        'form': form,
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I have done many searches on the topic, but all project examples, or help around the subject seems fairly outdated.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated! Many thanks.

Comment: So, what happens if the form is valid, but there is no matching user or the user is not active? There's no form error, but you fall through and redisplay the form anyway.

Comment: In any case, you should probably use the built-in [AuthenticationForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm) which wraps up the authentication/active check within the form validation itself.